# Using complex characters in YAML:

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to use YAML to format an email which a python script sends but the email has ascii art in the body which yaml is mistaking for another key. How do i make the message within a key use special characters like _/( etc?

Here is the

```
MESSAGE: 
  Dear {santa},


  This year you are {santee}'s Secret Santa! Ho Ho Ho!


  The maximum spending limit is $50.00


  ------------------------------------------------------------------

  Please Note

  ------------------------------------------------------------------


  This message was automatically generated by secretSanta.py


  Do not reply to this email as no one is monitoring the inbox


  If there are any questions, comments, concerns, etc please email email@gmail.com


  New matches can be generated in the case of extenuating circumstance


  Happy Gifting,

  TheSecretSantaRobot

           _
          {_}
          / \
         /   \
        /_____\
      {`_______`}
       //[] []\\
      (/(__7__)\)
      |'-' = `-'|
      |         |
      /\       /\
     /  '.   .'  \
    /_/   `"`   '\_\
   {__}###[_]###{__}
   (_/\_________/\_)
       |___|___|
        |--|--|
       (__)`(__)
```

If i take out the santa art it sends fine, but i get a KeyError with it and i dont know where to put quotes to eliminate the errors

Comment: You might consider editing and just asking the piece in the edit which seems to be the only relevant part.

Comment: done, you're right, otherwise its confusing

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the literal scalar indicator, `|`, to indicate that the indented lines are a single scalar (YAML parlance for string) whose formatting should be preserved:

```
MESSAGE: |
  Dear {santa},

  ...snip...

           _
          {_}
          / \
         /   \
        /_____\
      {`_______`}
       //[] []\\
      (/(__7__)\)
      |'-' = `-'|
      |         |
      /\       /\
     /  '.   .'  \
    /_/   `"`   '\_\
   {__}###[_]###{__}
   (_/\_________/\_)
       |___|___|
        |--|--|
       (__)`(__)
```